# Problema con Laravel Passport - Error ‘Invalid key supplied

Tags: laravel, passport, digitalocean

Estoy experimentando un problema con mi aplicación Laravel que está alojada en la plataforma de aplicaciones de DigitalOcean. La aplicación utiliza Laravel Passport para la autenticación y estoy recibiendo un error “Invalid key supplied” de manera intermitente.

El error se produce tanto al intentar autenticarme como al intentar acceder a las rutas protegidas. Aquí está el mensaje de error completo que veo en mi archivo laravel.log:

> producction.ERROR: invalid key supplied {"userId": 2, "exception": "[object] (LoginException(code: 0): invalid key supplied at /workspace/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php:67)"}

He verificado que los archivos `oauth-private.key` y `oauth-public.key` existen en el directorio storage y tienen los permisos correctos (`-rw-r--r--`). El propietario de estos archivos es apps, que creo que es el usuario que ejecuta el servidor web.

También he configurado las rutas a estas claves en mi archivo .env utilizando rutas absolutas, como se muestra a continuación:

```sh
PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY="file:///workspace/storage/oauth-private.key"
PASSPORT_PUBLIC_KEY="file:///workspace/storage/oauth-public.key"
```

A pesar de estos pasos, el problema persiste. ¿Alguien ha experimentado un problema similar o tiene alguna sugerencia sobre cómo podría resolverlo? Cualquier ayuda sería muy apreciada.

Comment: Prueba usando el helper `storage_path()` en vez de hardcodear el path al archivo https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-storage-path

Comment: Tienes que poner la ruta absoluta, quita el protocolo `file :` y luego haz un `php artisan passport:key` o  `php artisan passport:keys` que no recuerdo si key es singular o plural

Answer (score 0):

Is necessary rebuild the permission to generate the token with the oauth

`php artisan passport:install`

After that update your files with the new generated id and key

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! La respuesta debe estar en el idioma del sitio.